# Can't get pandas dataframe.to_html to scale/fit into bootstrap table

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I'm taking a 100 days of web code course, and one of the first projects is to build *anything* with the basic flask knowledge I've learned in days 1-4.

Now, as I work with dataframes a lot, I thought I would create a dataframe that tracks my progress, then render this via a bootstrap 4 table.

However, when I do this the dataframe content shrinks and it's extremely small :

[image]

now, when I remove the jinja templating code and just use statically typed data it scales to the page so unsure what I'm missing here, going over the pandas.to_html and a few hours of SO googling has made me none the wiser.

my code is as follows :

data frame

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': ['1-4', '5-9', '10', '11', '12'],
                   'Project': ["Flask", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown"],
                   'Status': ['In Progress', 'Not Started', 'Not Started','Not Started','Not Started']})
```

routes file :

```
from program import app, charts as c, df as d
import datetime
from flask import render_template


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')

def index():
    return render_template('index.html',tables=[d.df.to_html(classes=["table-bordered", "table-striped", "table-hover"])],
    titles = d.df.columns
    )

@app.route('/100Days')
def p100days():
    return render_template('100Days.html')

@app.route('/bar')

def bar():
    bar_labels = c.labels
    bar_values = c.values
    return render_template('bar.html', title='myChart', max=0.1, labels=bar_labels, values=bar_values)
```

and finally my bs4 table on my index page :

```
 <table class="table" id='myTable'>
 {% for table in tables %}
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">{{titles[loop.index]}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>{{ table|safe }}
  {% endfor %}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

{% endblock %}
```

please let me know if this is not a minimum example or if any additional information is required.

the table should look like the example table from the BS4 Table Documentation here :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/content/tables/

Answer (score 0):

You might need to adjust your classes like this:

```
    return render_template('index.html',tables=[d.df.to_html(classes=["table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"])],
```

I had to submit them as a single string for them to work. And I needed to have plain `table` in front there.